# How do I speed up and cache mmap file access over NFS on Linux?

Tags: linux, nfs, cache

The server and client are both 64-bit Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

The application in question is a custom app that uses `mmap()` for fast random file access. Its ideal state is when the entire file is cached in RAM.

The network connections are really fast 10Gb Ethernet. It is a virtual server blade setup.

It isn't the network connections slowing things down because everything performs superbly when using a virtual disk (iSCSI to the SAN). But when we run the application on a NFS home directory mount, performance goes to the dogs.

It appears that the Linux kernel isn't caching *anything*. So it is reading every single disk block needed by `mmap()` accesses over and over and over again.

The NFS mount is done through autofs, which has only default settings. `/proc/mounts` shows the NFS mount is done with the following options:

> rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=192.168.11.52,mountvers=3,mountproto=tcp,addr=192.168.11.52

How can I make Ubuntu 10.04 cache the file instead of reloading it all the time?

Comment: What MMAP flags are you passing?

Comment: I'd certainly suggest using nfs v4.  It should help because of the byte range reservations

Answer (score 3):

Have you tuned your NFS exports or mounts at all? What are your present mount options? Which filesystem are you using on the NFS server?

I know you're using Ubuntu, but this [NFS tuning guide from Red Hat](http://www.redhat.com/f/pdf/rhel4/NFSv4WP.pdf) might be a good start, especially if you have a good performance metric to test with different settings. Some of the hints in the document cover limiting metadata changes when accessing files over NFS and extending the attributes cache.

Is [NFS caching](https://web.archive.org/web/20111210130024/http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7378/) (FS-Cache, CacheFS) an option in this case?

Comment: Sequential read/write runs at 80MB/s per second, so that part of the NFS tuning is okay.

Comment: Right, but look at the attributes side of things. The application you describe may have an impact on access times and caching the attributes may make a difference, depending on how you're benchmarking.

Comment: NFS caching with CacheFS will make things worse in his case. His local disks are likely slower than his network.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Right. Since these are virtual systems there aren't any real local disks. It's all virtual. The "local disk" is a VMware image backed by iSCSI.

Comment: I added some info about proc mounts to the question.